# Python Suds: how to get an xsd:timeInstant instead of xsd:date in request?

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am trying to work with a webservice that needs xsd:timeInstant in a request (see WSDL):

```
<xsd:complexType name="QueryParams">
       <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="start" type="xsd:timeInstant" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="stop" type="xsd:timeInstant" minOccurs="0"/>                    
        </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The resulting SOAP XML request should therefore contain something like this:

```
<start xsi:type="xsd:timeInstant">2009-05-10T17:00:00Z</start>
<stop xsi:type="xsd:timeInstant">2009-05-11T17:00:00Z</stop>
```

With SUDS, I created the following object:

```
qp = client.factory.create("ns0:QueryParams")
qp.start = "2009-05-10T17:00:00Z"
qp.stop = "2009-06-10T17:00:00Z"
```

Unfortunately, SUDS is turning this into an xsd:date which is refused by the server.

```
<query xsi:type="ns3:QueryParams">
    <start xsi:type="ns1:date">2009-05-10T17:00:00Z</start>
    <stop xsi:type="ns1:date">2009-06-10T17:00:00Z</stop>
</query>
```

Any thoughts how to force an xsd:timeInstant?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found the solution, so might as well post the answer for future reference.

In the suds/xsd/sxbuiltin.py file, there is a Factory class

```
class Factory:

    tags =\
    {
        # any
        'anyType' : XAny,
        ...
        # dates & times
        ...
        'gMonth' : XString,
```

Under gMonth, I added

```
'timeInstant' : XString,
```

The WSDL type xsd:timeInstant is now copied properly. The SOAP request XML shows this:

```
<query xsi:type="ns3:QueryParams">
    <start xsi:type="ns1:timeInstant">2009-05-10T17:00:00Z</start>
    <stop xsi:type="ns1:timeInstant">2009-06-10T17:00:00Z</stop>
</query>
```

And the server is able to handle this input.